# Receiving input from command line in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, command-line

I need to write a Java program that accepts input from the command line and stores those inputs into an array. A for loop should go through the inputs and print them out.

My code so far is:

```
public class HelloName{    
    public static void main(String args []){    
       for( int i = 0; i < args.length ; i++) {    
              System.out.print("Hello " + args[i]);               
       }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when more than one input is entered, it  will show "Hello" twice.

For instance, writing `java HelloName John Doe`, will give me:

```
Hello John Hello Doe
```

I would simply like to know how to get the names to combine to Hello John Doe.

Comment: thats because you print the "hello" inside your loop

Comment: Think why it is printing every time for each argument, you will guess right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String args []){
    System.out.print("Hello ");
    for( int i = 0; i < args.length ; i++) {
        System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

In your code hello was printed for each argument because it was inside your loop.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are appending a `Hello` in the `println()`. Delete that and you are good to go.

What is happening is this: for every iteration you are printing `Hello` followed by the `i`th element of the `args[]` array. Hence, you get repeated `Hello`s

Print the `Hello` before you enter the loop and then iterate over the `args[]`

```
public class HelloName{

    public static void main(String args []){
       System.out.println("Hello ");
       for( int i = 0; i < args.length ; i++) {

              System.out.print(args[i] + " "); // see the difference ?

       }
    }
```

You may run the corrected program on IDEOne here: http://ideone.com/oriBtP

Answer (score 0):

The blank space between the two words is treated as a delimiter for input arguments. So John Doe is treated as 2 arguments and you get your output.

If you intention is to input only one name with the space in between, such as "John Doe", you will need to change the input parameter format to indicate as such. So keeping your program same, change the invocation to this:

> java HelloName "John Doe" "Adam Smith"

Your output will then be

```
Hello John Doe
Hello Adam Smith
```